# How to force focus on TextInput with changable editable prop - REACT-NATIVE

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a `TextInput` box I would like to display as Text. Then when it made `editable` by clicking the edit button, the input will be in focus.

Currently it will focus on button press when editable is not set, however does not work when this is set.

I have tried:
- removing editable
- recreating error in snack

SNACK: https://snack.expo.io/HyRFapVYH

relevant code:

```js
export default () =>  {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('Rei');
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

  const input = useRef(null);
  const onPress = () => {
    setActive(!active);
    input.current.focus();
  };

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput 
          style={styles.paragraph}
          value={value}
          onChangeText={setValue}
          ref={input}
          selectTextOnFocus
          editable={active}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={onPress}>
        <Text>{ active? `Save me` : `Edit me`}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
}
```

I expect the TextInput to be in focus and text highlighted when I click the edit button.

Comment: your code here is not the same as the snack, in your snack you set editable={false},
thats why you cant change the value of the input text. I just copy paste your code here to the snack and it's working fine..

Comment: to improve it change your onPress to :     const onPress = () => {
    setActive(!active);
    if(!active){
      input.current.focus();
    }
  };

,  So your input value wont get selected when you click on "save"

Comment: Oh oops, that was me playing around with options. It works on web display, but does not work on IOS or android devices.

Comment: On android it's working fine, but in IOS it's not selecting the Input Value i don't know why :  https://pastebin.com/5m513b5k

Comment: Thanks for double checking! I'll raise an bug with react native.

Answer (score 0):

this will fix the dynamic editable focus issue

```
const FixFocus = () => {

const [value, setValue] = useState('Rei');
const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

const input = useRef(null);
const onPress = () => {
    setActive(!active);
    input.current.focus();
};

**add this block **
useEffect(() => {
    if (active) {
        input?.current?.focus();
    }
}, [active])

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
            style={styles.paragraph}
            value={value}
            onChangeText={setValue}
            ref={input}
            selectTextOnFocus
            editable={active}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={onPress}>
            <Text>{active ? `Save me` : `Edit me`}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
);
```

}